# Помогите создать SQL запрос

Tags: sql, запрос, insert

Есть 3 таблицы: автор, книга, покупки.
Поля автора (AUTHOR_ID, NAME).
Поля книги (BOOK_ID, AUTHOR_ID, NAME).
Поля покупок (BOOK_ID, DATE_ORDER(дата покупки).

Нужно добавить 2 книги тем авторам, которые написали свою первую книгу после 2010.01.01.

Знаю только как выбрать этих авторов, а как добавить им по 2 книги нет. 
Помогите пожалуйста.

```
SELECT *
FROM(
    SELECT DISTINCT name_author, Authors.Code_author,
        MIN(Date_order) OVER (PARTITION BY name_author) AS Min_date
    FROM Authors
    INNER JOIN Books ON Books.Code_author = Authors.Code_author
    INNER JOIN Purchases ON Purchases.Code_book = Books.Code_book
    ) AS x
WHERE Min_date > '20170101 00:00:00 AM'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не очень понятно, откуда брать эти две книги и что нужно делать с таблицей покупок. Вот такой запрос, например, добавляет каждому автору, который написал свою первую книгу после 2010.01.01, две книги Book5 и Book6.

```
INSERT INTO Book (AUTHOR_ID, NAME, DATE)
SELECT AUTHOR_ID, InsBook.InsName, CAST(InsBook.InsDate AS TIMESTAMP)
FROM (SELECT '2010-1-1' as InsDate, 'Book5' as InsName UNION 
SELECT '2010-1-1', 'Book6') InsBook,
Book
JOIN (SELECT MIN(ID) as MinID FROM Book GROUP BY AUTHOR_ID)
BookMin ON BookMin.MinID = Book.ID
WHERE Date > '2010-1-1'
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f2a0a/1)

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!